# Summing Cells Upward Until A Blank Cell Is Reached

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula (not VBA) that sum cells upward until a blank cell is reached in the column on the left. The cells filled with red indicate where I need a formula.

[image]

E.g. 355 = 15 + 25 + 30 + 15 + 95 + 45 + 130

Comment: You will have to put the formula individually in each cell.  It would better to put the total in a different column, then you would be able to just drag it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind putting the results into a different column, one solution would be to calculate the running sum in a third column, making sure to zero it out if a blank cell is found, like so:

[image: solution]

The highlighted formula is on cell `C2`, and can be dragged down on the `C` column.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1);B2;B2+C1)
```